# How to remove e.preventDefault() in order to allow "cut copy paste" from following script

Tags: javascript

I need to bypass the following written script in order to allow "cut copy paste" .. thanx in advance

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content, #message_content').on("cut copy paste", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('#content, #message_content').off("cut copy paste");`

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content, #message_content').on("cut copy paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#content, #message_content').off("cut copy paste");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">Hello</div>
<textarea id="message_content">Cut and paste me</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who comes here and is not sure how to actually use the answers provided:
Use the script suggested by Alon Eitan and just paste it into your developer toolbar under *console* and press enter.

`$('#content, #message_content').off("cut copy paste");`